# Change a global variable in a function

Tags: javascript

I can not figure this out...

I want to:

declare a variable, run a function that changes the value of that variable and then then alert the value of the new value.

Like so:

```
function loadApp(){
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
            var posLat;
            getLocation();
        console.log(posLat);
    });
}


    function getLocation(){

        posLat = "hey";

}
```

The alert should display 4 but just alerts undefined. Am i bein stupid?

Comment: Perhaps you are running an old version of the code. Refresh the cache to be sure.

Comment: I have edited the code with exactly what I haved. I used the previous code as an example.

Comment: `posLat` isn't global in that example... at least not the one inside the `function(response) {...` part.

Comment: In your example, you're logging the local variable `posLat` which doesn't have a value, but you're still updating the global variable `posLat`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`posLat` is defined inside a function, therefore making it a local function that cannot be used outside of its surround scope. That's why `getLocation` can't modify it. In fact, it's creating a global variable called `posLat` on the window object. As the comments on my post suggest, set `posLat` to the return value of `getLocation`:

```
var posLat = getLocation();

...

function getLocation() {
    return "hey";
}
```

Comment: So can i not work my code this way then? Shall I declare the var posLat at the begining of the code?

Comment: @nmyster: Yes, that would work. However, you *should* not use global variables like this at. Use a `return` statement and profit!

Comment: okay, I think ill shall declare my variables at the beginning because getLocation gets the lat and long and then sets a google Api marker. However I was testing how to change variable values in a function.

Comment: @nmyster There is another way actually. Passing the variable as an element in an array instead. Like this: `getLocation( [posLat] )`. And then in the `getLocation` function you'd do this: `function getLocation(array){ array[0] = "hey"; }`. This works because arrays are passed by *reference* and not by value like normal variables.

Comment: @David: Returning values via array references like that is an ugly, ugly hack and is just probably just strictly worse then simply returning the values. Just return the value normaly if your function is synchronous or "return" it by passing it to the success callback if the code is async.